# Objective C Block - How to extract Blocks Data (Facebook SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, multithreading

I am suffering with it a few hours now.

I am trying to retrieve data from the **Facebook API** using the `Facebook SDK 3.5` for iOS. When I issue a request using the method `startWithCompletionHandler()` it does not seem to dispatch a new thread, as it waits for the whole function to end, and only afterwards the block content is executed. So I am not able to read the userData contents in other areas of the class.

I have tried with semaphores but it always seems to fall in a deadlock.

*userData* is global.

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];        
    // Send request to Facebook
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
            userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

            NSLog(@"Block return: %@",userData[@"id"]);

        } else{
            NSLog(@"Facebook Initialization error: %@", error);
        }
    }
     ];
```

Comment: Hey Leonardo. I don't think that the method of FB SDK you are using is causing the problem. As far as I know, none of the request methods of FB SDK blocks the main thread, they return immediately. You should double check other parts of your code for the operations that could block the main thread.

Comment: The completion block doesn't wait for the function to end.. it just runs asynchronously (without blocking the thread, so the rest of the code executes normally), and it needs some time to send and receive the response from the server. You need to do your stuff inside the callback, not in other places of the class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
    }
    else {

        [self StopSpinner];

        txtID.text = user.id;
        txtUserName.text = user.username;
        txtName.text = user.name;
        txtEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Your answer is not solving the problem. Please, consider reading the question.

Comment: Not OKKK. Maybe your code will solve the problem in your eyes, but actually, it doesn't, and your code will block the thread that completionHandler runs till it loads the profile picture. Did you know that?

Comment: Yes, I did, but now, I forgot... How could I?

Comment: In order to identify the problem and provide the solution, first I have to identify the problem. But, I don't see the problem in the code that Leonardo provided. That's why I don't have any solution yet... It's not about my knowledge at all.

Comment: `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` this line will block the main thread (the callback is called in the main thread if I'm not mistaken). Other than that it looks ok.

Answer (score -1):

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];        
    // Send request to Facebook
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
            userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
            // do what you want to do or call any other methods.    



        } else{
            NSLog(@"Facebook Initialization error: %@", error);
        }
    }
     ];
```

I m not sure there is other way to do this.

Comment: This is the original code minus one log statement. How does this answer the question in any way?

Comment: answer is in that line, he wanted to execute statement after getting response. he can write it in that block.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your answer was to replace the original log statement with a comment. That doesn't really answer the question at all. Please update your answer with some additional information explaining how this solves the problem.

Comment: I dont think i can explain better than this, simply i am saying that he can write statements in that particular block which ever he wants to execute after getting response from facebook.

Answer (score -3):

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];        
    // Send request to Facebook
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,  NSDictionary * result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
            userData = result;

            NSLog(@"Block result: %@",[userData objectForkey:@"Your key"]);

        } else{
            NSLog(@"Facebook Initialization error: %@", error);
        }
    }
     ];
```

in place of id result ,You can use NSDictionary * result and get block result as per your dictionary key, Make sure your userData dictionary is allocted.

Comment: Please read the question. Simply changing the parameter type in the callback has nothing to do with the problem.