# Facebook startWithCompletionHandler data error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Thank you in advance for helping out.

Still unable to proceed after searching around for hours. The closes match is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376570/objective-c-block-how-to-extract-blocks-data-facebook-sdk) but it's yet to be solve.

Having trouble setting facebook data to an NSMutableArray, although NSLog is able to display the friend.name in the console log:

// additional info(NSMutableArray *arrContact in FBLContactTableViewController.h)

// Code in FBLViewController.m:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary* result,NSError *error) {

    NSMutableArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; 
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count); // returns: Found : 1 friends
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
       NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@", friend.name); // returns: I have a friend named Boss
       self.profilePic.profileID = friend.id;
       self.profilePic.pictureCropping = FBProfilePictureCroppingSquare;
    }

    FBLContactTableViewController *contactTableViewController = [[FBLContactTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    // shows 0 object for friends. friends is not set into arrContact
    // why is it so???
    [contactTableViewController.arrContact arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:friends]; 
    [self presentViewController:contactTableViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

## Edited - Result after alloc init NSMutableArray friends

[Result image - friend array still empty](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/ScreenShot2013-11-28at31130PM_zpse12f1611.png)

## NSLog for result dictionary

```
first_name = BOSS;
id = 100007105510987;
last_name = Last;
name = "Boss Last";
```

Comment: initWithNibName:nil ??

Comment: describes your errors

Comment: @iDev there's no error. The problem is the "NSMutableArray friends" data is not pass on to the FBLContactTableViewController "NSMutableArray arrContact". Although I can NSLog e.g friends.name to the console log, "contactTableViewController.arrContact" stays empty

Comment: @AravindBG Have changed it to FBLContactTableViewController *contactTableViewController = [[FBLContactTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBLContactTableViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: @AravindBG Thanks for correcting that error. The main issue still persist, friend array is still empty. And I don't know why.

Comment: did you log this [result objectForKey:@"data"]; what is the output

Comment: @AravindBG I've posted the result above under "NSLog for result dictionary" header. and also this which is insignificant: Dic {
    next = "https://graph.facebook.com/100007120809545/friends?fields=last_name,id,name,first_name,username&format=json&access_token=CAAD0A3vaU9IBAFF5poRPBwJ4OZBqkJfbk5c2dNOI9kYZCcD7MMZAnQZCUIxJngwL7HZBXEABw9yQad5ZCTZCXPGYhJIWsyvQ6iwvlTYXQMcUXgNcPSxnY5XhoHULZAkthwFEnZArVB0AGC7ScvtZBw1kCKyR4Qq8ET8izPLsBenZB2KxBP6FRtk99kn&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100007105510987";
}

Comment: okk just above [contactTableViewController.arrContact arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:friends]; Log friends, is it display expected output?

Comment: are you trying to pass friend or friends??

Comment: @AravindBG passing friends NSMutableArray.NSLog friends above  [contactTableViewController.arrContact arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:friends]; works fine.

Comment: Ok now what is the status?

Comment: hmm...Still unable to pass friends NSMutableArray into contactTableViewController.arrContact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alloc your  NSMutableArray then only should crate array stack for your object.

```
 NSMutableArray* friends=[NSMutableArry alloc]init];
```

Thanks

Comment: friend array still empty. (http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/ScreenShot2013-11-28at31130PM_zpse12f1611.png)

Comment: Thanks @iDev and AravindBG Found the culprit. Cause by the NSMutableArray in the .m file. Thanks again.